# Create a recursive json schema which is generic

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to create a json schema for a json file. The structure of the json is generic and I am trying to create a generic schema for json files which contain a similar structure to the one shown below.

```
**Json file:**
{
    "Soccer League": {
        "lvl": "Championships",
        "state": "1",
        "Clubs": {
            "Rosely": {
                "Boys": {"id": "A1", "state": "Ready"},
                "Girls": {
                    "id": "A2",
                    "state": "Ready",
                    "Substitutes": {
                        "id": "A3",
                        "state": "Sitting",
                        "Goalkeepers": {
                            "Players": {"id": "A4", "state": "Idle"},
                            "id": "A5",
                            "state": "Idle",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            "Division League": {
                "TeamA": {
                    "PlayersA": {
                        "id": "A6",
                        "status": "Ready",
                        "CoachA": {"id": "A7", "state": "Ready"},
                    },
                    "PlayersB": {
                        "id": "A8",
                        "state": "Playing",
                        "CoachB": {"id": "A9", "state": "Idle"},
                    },
                }
            },
        },
    }
}
```

```
**Json-schema:**
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Soccer League": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "lvl": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Clubs": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Rosely": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "Boys": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "id": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "state": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "id",
                    "state"
                  ]
                },
                "Girls": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "id": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "state": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Substitutes": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "id": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "state": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "Goalkeepers": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "Players": {
                              "type": "object",
                              "properties": {
                                "id": {
                                  "type": "string"
                                },
                                "state": {
                                  "type": "string"
                                }
                              },
                              "required": [
                                "id",
                                "state"
                              ]
                            },
                            "id": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "state": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          },
                          "required": [
                            "Players",
                            "id",
                            "state"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "required": [
                        "id",
                        "state",
                        "Goalkeepers"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "id",
                    "state",
                    "Substitutes"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "Boys",
                "Girls"
              ]
            },
            "Division League": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "TeamA": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "PlayersA": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "id": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "status": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "CoachA": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "id": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "status": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          },
                          "required": [
                            "id",
                            "status"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "required": [
                        "id",
                        "status",
                        "CoachA"
                      ]
                    },
                    "PlayersB": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "id": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "status": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "CoachB": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "id": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "status": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          },
                          "required": [
                            "id",
                            "status"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "required": [
                        "id",
                        "status",
                        "CoachB"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "PlayersA",
                    "PlayersB"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "TeamA"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "Rosely",
            "Division League"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "lvl",
        "state",
        "Clubs"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Soccer League"
  ]
}
```

As we can see from above, we have many same layers but just with different names. I am unsure on how to create a recursive json schema for json files which will follow a similar format. This is sort of hard-coded, but how to make it generic.

I am new to json schema and would appreciate if someone could help me infer a schema from the json above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `definitions` to reuse chunks of schemas. You should probably use such for defining a player, and then reference the definition. There doesn't look like much else that's duplicated, at least not that I can immediatly see.

Comment: @Relequestual As we can see that each of them has "id" and "state". For example, in Rosely--->Boys, we could have a nested structure like this ```"Goalkeepers": {
                            "Players": {"id": "A4", "state": "Idle"},
                            "id": "A5",
                            "state": "Idle",
                        }```. May you help me with a code snippet on how to use ```definitions```. I am really confused :/.

Comment: You can reference a definition which references itself. It looks like your structure requires specific key names though. It is possible to reduce the duplication quite a bit, but it would take quite a bit of work to do and explain. I can't help further today, sorry.

Comment: @Relequestual I tried something like this. ```{
  "definitions": {
    "type": "object", "properties": { "FFSD": { "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }, "required": [ "FFSD" ]
      },
      "IOSSystem": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "PanelA": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/IOSSystem"
          }
        }
      },
         "$ref": "#/definitions/IOSSystem"
    }
  }
}```

Comment: Take a look at http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#reuse

Comment: @Relequestual I tried but I am still confused. :/

Comment: `definitions` must be an object, where each value is a JSON Schema which you then use the key to reference. Can you see this in the example I linked? Can you see how the `definitions` you have tried is different?

Comment: @Relequestual Still no success. I am still unable to come up with a valid schema. I have tried so much. Can you please help me out? I would be so grateful.

Comment: Happy to help, but please answer the above questions first.

Comment: I see the definitions example and I am not sure how it is different from what I did?

Comment: In your pasted `definitions` object, you have the value as a schema, where the value should be an object where each key is a defined schema name, and the values should be schemas. See the difference now?

Comment: I am a bit confused. So do i need to create multiple defintions?

Comment: For me to help further, you're going to need to join the JSON Schema slack (discussion link on the JSON Schema site) so we can chat. Comments on StackOverflow are not the place for long form discussion. =]